# Is it possible to install audio driver on ubuntu server 20 04 lts?

Tags: sound

I installed ubuntu server 20.04 lts and I want to know if it is possible to install audio drivers on this system. I know it sounds absurd because it's a server, but I'm blind and I use the screen reader and I need audio.

Comment: If you need the machine to have audio, then it would be simpler to use Ubuntu Desktop as a server. You can run all of your server applications on Ubuntu Desktop just fine 

Comment: But is posible or not? I want know this work

Comment: It is possible, yes, though a good deal of work. The audio system may be in place already, you’ll have to check with `lspci` and, if it’s installed, PulseAudio. The user accounts will need to be added to the `audio` group before they can work with audio devices in any meaningful way, too.

Comment: Thank you very much, but you can explain to me in more detail how I could do this, or if you know certain resources / guides that I could follow.